# Modal en MDI y sus JInternalFrame Java

Tags: java, modal

## Modal en MDI y sus JInternalFrame Java

Hola necesito saber como manejar modal en un MDI Java, lo que quisiera hacer es manejar el bloqueos de ventanas de la siguiente manera:

> Caso 1:

JInternalFrame -> JInternalFrame

> Caso 2:

MDI -> JFrame

Tengo un caso que tengo que buscar por decir, datos de otras tablas y pasarsela a la que la llamo, pero que si el cursor da clic fuera de las margenes de la segunda ventana que no se oculte hasta que seleccione una dato o cierre la ventana manualmente.

Answer (score 0):

Es sencillo hacer una ventana modal en java, te muestro un ejemplo

```
final JDialog frame = new JDialog(parentFrame, frameTitle, true);
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

y en caso de requerir mas ayuda te comparto el siguiente enlace

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html